# How to make checking values for errors more efficient

Tags: r, performance, error-correction

I am dealing with around 700 large datasets (with ~ 80 variables and up to 200k rows per dataset). Most variables are only allowed to be within a certain range or to be certain values. There are some errors in each dataset with values that do not adhere to these rules.

So, somehow I need to find those errors and make them NA. Currently I am doing this the following way:

```
library(data.table)
dataset$variable[!dataset$variable %in% c(1,2,3)] <- NA
# or
dataset$variable[!(dataset$variable >= 0 &
                   dataset$variable <= 150)] <- NA
... # for 80 variables
```

My issue is that applying these rules takes some time (up to 10 secs) and I would like to speed up that process. Do you have any ideas how to make it more efficient? Or is this already the simplest way and I have to deal with it?

Thank you so much in advance!

---

*Edit: I am wondering for example: Would it be faster to iterate over the rows instead of the columns?*

Comment: You could try using `data.table` package.  It might be a bit more efficient, at improving your times and uses the same syntax.  At 10 seconds for each data set, that puts you around 1.5 hours to process it all.  I would assume loading the data might take longer than actually processing it

Comment: I forgot to mention that - I already am using the ```data.table``` package. Would I then calling the wrong syntax? And yes, loading the data also takes a long time - that's why I would like to keep this part as short as possible.. Since I think there is not much savings potential in using ```fread``` as an alternative for ```read.csv```

Comment: What are you talking about? `fread` is ***so*** much faster than `read.csv`.

Comment: If you are using `data.table` then I would certainly stick with `fread` and subsetting.  Not sure if you are going to gain much efficiency.  Just load it and let her rip for a few hours.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad english might have been a bit misleading.. I mean this: Since I am already using ```fread``` I think I can't win much time anymore there.

Comment: OK, if you're using `fread`, it should be giving you a `data.table` by default. You can stick with `data.table` functions to gain some speed (see my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for pure performance, I suggest you check out the `data.table` package, which enhances `data.frame`s in R. `data.table` can do replacements in place, by reference (without copying). When you invoke the assignment operation (`<-`) in R, I believe that a copy of the data is made, which causes slowdowns for large data sets.

A `data.table` solution for your problem:

```
library(data.table)

# Cast as a data.table
dataset <- as.data.table(dataset)

# Do the replacement by reference with the := operation in data.table
# See ?`:=`
dataset[!variable %in% c(1,2,3), variable := NA]
dataset[variable >= 0 & variable <= 150, variable := NA]
```

This should be *much* faster than replacing values in a regular `data.frame` with `[<-`

Comment: Now only takes 2 instead of 10 seconds. Thank you so much!